# How on Ajax request genereate once divs for data and then on next ajax request update only the data in the divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, monitoring

Hi there I'm trying to populate div with data from ajax request, the idea is to use Ajax to get temperature from multiple sensors and for every sensor temperature data I want a separate div column with the data, So on document.ready I use ajax get once to popualte the main page div with the div columns to get the results, but after that I want to use ajax again every 10 seconds to update the data, but how can I do it not generating the containers for the data again? Because of waht I have right now I can't make it to work when I try to make a filter to show/hide the div for specific location.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


      var menu_list = [];
      var tr_str = [];
      var temp_int= [];

      $.ajax({
          url: 'getData.php',
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'JSON',
          success: function(response){
              var len = response.length;
              for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                  var location = response[i].location;
                  temp_int[i] = response[i].temp_int;
                  var temp = response[i].temp;
                  var hum = response[i].hum;
                  var dew = response[i].dew;

                  tr_str[i] = "<div id='locc" + i + "' class='location'>" +
                      "<span class='title'>" + location + "</span>" +
                      "<div class='temp" + i + "'><span>Temperatura: </span><span id='check'>" + temp + " &degC</span></div>" +
                      "<div><span>Względna wilgotność: </span><span>" + hum + " %RH</span></div>" +
                      "<div><span>Punkt rosy: </span><span>" + dew + " &degC</span></div>" +
                      "</div>";

                  menu_list[i] = "<label for='loc" + i + "'>" +
                      "<input type='checkbox' id='loc" + i + "' checked='checked'/>" +
                      "<span class='css-checkbox'></span>" +
                      "<p>" + location + "</p>" +
                      "</label>";

              }

              $("#nav").append(menu_list);
              $("#data").html(tr_str);

              for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                if (temp_int[i] >= 250) {
                $(".temp" + i).css("background-color", "#ff0000");
              }
              else if (temp_int[i] >= 235) {
                $('.temp' + i).css("background-color","#f1c40f");
              }
              else {
                $('.temp' +i).css("background-color","#3498db");
              }
            }



          }
      });


      $("#loc1").change(function () {
          if (this.checked){
            $("#locc1").show(!this.checked);
          }else {
            $("#locc1").hide(!this.checked);
          }
      });
    });

  setTimeout(fetchdata,5000);



function fetchdata(){

  var tr_str = [];
  var temp_int= [];

  $.ajax({
      url: 'getData.php',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      cache: false,
      success: function(response){
          var len = response.length;
          for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
              var location = response[i].location;
              temp_int[i] = response[i].temp_int;
              var temp = response[i].temp;
              var hum = response[i].hum;
              var dew = response[i].dew;

              tr_str[i] = "<div id='locc" + i + "' class='location'>" +
                  "<span class='title'>" + location + "</span>" +
                  "<div class='temp" + i + "'><span>Temperatura: </span><span id='check'>" + temp + " &degC</span></div>" +
                  "<div><span>Względna wilgotność: </span><span>" + hum + " %RH</span></div>" +
                  "<div><span>Punkt rosy: </span><span>" + dew + " &degC</span></div>" +
                  "</div>";

          }


          $("#data").html(tr_str);

          for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
            if (temp_int[i] >= 250) {
            $(".temp" + i).css("background-color", "#ff0000");
          }
          else if (temp_int[i] >= 235) {
            $('.temp' + i).css("background-color","#f1c40f");
          }
          else {
            $('.temp' +i).css("background-color","#3498db");
          }
        }

      },
      complete:function(){
        setTimeout(fetchdata,5000);
      }

  });
}



function openNav() {
   document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "350px";
      document.getElementById("data").style.marginLeft = "350px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("data").style.marginLeft = "0";
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div id="nav" class="menu">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <button>Uncheck all</button>
 </div>

  <div class="nav-wrapper">
  <span onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
 </div>


  <div id="data" class="wrapper"></div>

   
</body>
</html>
```

You can see that I use almost the same Ajax request again, is there a way to get teh data at first and generate the divs for the data and then just get the data every 10 seconds and update it only withou generating again the divs?

I'm thinking that what I have right now is making tis unable to work

```js
var $checkboxes = $("#nav :checkbox");
  var $button = $("#nav button");
  
  function allChecked(){
    return $checkboxes.length === $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
  }
  
  function updateButtonStatus(){
    $button.text(allChecked()? "Uncheck all" : "Check all");
  }
  
  function handleButtonClick(){
    $checkboxes.prop("checked", allChecked()? false : true)
  }
 
  $button.on("click", function() {
    handleButtonClick();
    updateButtonStatus();
    checking();
  });

  $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
    updateButtonStatus();
  });
  
  function openNav() {
   document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "0";
  } 

  function checking() {
   var temps = <?php echo json_encode($temps); ?>;  //I know this is wrong I would change the loop iteration but it is not working even for one static element when I change it.
   $.each( temps, function( index, value ){      

      $('#loc'+index).change(function () {               
      if( this.checked ) {
       $('#locc'+index).show(!this.checked);
      } else {
       $('#locc'+index).hide(!this.checked);
      }         
      }).change();
  });}
```

Here is the php file code I'm geting using ajax:

```html
<?php

require 'lib/locations.php';
  $search = array('STRING: ', '"');
  $search2 = array('INTEGER: ', '"');
  $replace = array('','');
  $return_arr = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {

  $temp_int = snmpget($ips[$i], $community, ".1.3.6.1.4.1.22626.1.2.3.1.0");
  $temp_int = str_replace($search2,$replace,$temp_int);

  $temp = snmpget($ips[$i], $community, ".1.3.6.1.4.1.22626.1.2.1.1.0");
  $temp = str_replace($search,$replace,$temp);
  $hum = snmpget($ips[$i], $community, ".1.3.6.1.4.1.22626.1.2.1.2.0");
  $hum = str_replace($search,$replace,$hum);
  $dew = snmpget($ips[$i], $community, ".1.3.6.1.4.1.22626.1.2.1.3.0");
  $dew = str_replace($search,$replace,$dew);
  $loc = $location[$i];

  $return_arr[] = array("location" => $loc,
             "temp_int" => $temp_int,
             "temp" => $temp,
             "hum" => $hum,
             "dew" => $dew);

  }

echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

The generated data is an array of one integer and strings

something like this:

```js
var response =[{
"location": "location_1"
"temp_int":250,
"temp":"30.5",
"hum":"49.8",
"dew":"8.5"
},
{"location": "location_1"
"temp_int":250,
"temp":"30.5",
"hum":"49.8",
"dew":"8.5"
}, etc.]
```

Comment: please post your Json data

Comment: @kalai I updated the question with the code that generates the json data

Comment: i am not a php developer,so you can post your json data, i will try with myself.

Comment: @kalai I update the question again